# Need help in defining and calling(using) Static variable in ts, it is always undefined

Tags: typescript, variables, static

```
export class myClass implements OnInit {

counter=0;
static counter:any;

onListItemClick(PackDef: PackDefinition): void {
this.itemClicked.emit(PackDef);
this.counter++;
console.log(this.counter);
```

}

and..

```
import { myClass } from '../../../';
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result: any) => {
this.saveMyMethod();
console.log("Final1"),
console.log(myClass.counter);
});

saveMyMethod(): void {
console.log("Final2"),
console.log(myClass.counter);
```

}
}

Do you know why I cant have correct counter after "Final1" or "Final2"? but I have a correct counter in myClass.

Comment: You have two counters, one static, the other instance member. The static is not initialized or incremented so it remains `undefined`.

Comment: if I delete  counter=0 ( deleting the instance one) how should I initialized or incremented it? Would you please help?

Comment: If you really want to have it `static` you need to qualify it with `myClass`. You can use this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEC2CeBhcVoG8BQHrQgFzDwEthpgB7AVwDs8BTAJ2gF5oAGAbixyOuAbqw6tABQBKAFzQAbuSIATdNhxwkKCADoKNegwDUerirLlqEciDoaQ5AOYiABr36Dh9RXnLQAJGgTJITW1aRgBfBzEjaFCMGIwKMzxoXnwWaGo6AHdVAKhxLnjTc0trOxF-dS0qEIZIrBS8DWcBIVE6wrMLKxt7CsCqnUY6oA) for reference.

Comment: Would you please help me in this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73141256/count-of-last-added-subitems-to-the-parent-item-in-the-nested-list-ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try again with follow code below:

```
export class myClass implements OnInit {
static counter:any = 0;
static onListItemClick(PackDef: PackDefinition): void {
this.counter++;
console.log(this.counter);
}
```

Comment: it gives me NaN!

Comment: i just update my answer. I just add the keyword 'static' before your function.

Comment: if i make my function static, I have to declare "itemClicked" static which i dont want.. As I have                                                                                 onListItemClick(PackDef: PackDefinition): void {
this.itemClicked.emit(PackDef);
this.counter++;
console.log(this.counter);

Comment: Would you please help me in this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73141256/count-of-last-added-subitems-to-the-parent-item-in-the-nested-list-ts

Answer (score 0):

Are you write code with js?
js are not support type **any** and your define variable is use for ts.
Try again with follow code below:

```
static counter = 0;
```

Comment: sorry, my bad, i want to write it in ts.